# ExtJs hiddenName config

Tags: extjs, extjs4

reading the sources, if I set hiddenName config in a combobox, extjs will create an input type hidden in the dom.

But, to this value to be send to server, I need to create a hiddenField manually:

my combo:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
valueField: 'recid',
hiddenName : 'recid',
name: 'description',
submitValue:false,
displayField: 'description'
```

my hiddenField:

```
xtype: 'hiddenfield',
name: 'recid'
```

My hidden field receives the "recid" value.
The hidden input created by extjs receives "description" value.

What's wrong ?

Comment: what is the reason for doing this?

Comment: I want to fill the combobox of my form without the need to go to the server, because the id and text already is in the store of my grid.

Comment: You don't need hiddenName for that, in fact, in Ext4, that technique is not used anymore, not by the user, at least. If you only want to fill your combo with an existing store, just put `store: myStore` at its config.